# Laravel eloquent - Merge parent $appends

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Let's suppose I have two Models, `Veichle` and `Car`.

```
Veichle extends Model {
    $appends = ['append_1', 'append_2'];
}
```

and

```
Car extends Veichle {
    $appends = ['append_3', 'append_4'];
}
```

How can I use `append_1` if I have Car object? In this way the Car class just override the parent $appends, I didn't find any method to merge it

Comment: So you want to use all the appends in the Vehicle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in the constructor by using the `append` method as it will append the provided attributes to the existing ones:

```
Car extends Vehicle
{
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->append(['append_3', 'append_4']);
    }
}
```